# I have include wp-config, should I add global $wpdb also?

Tags: database, wpdb, wp-config

Usually, In my wordpress website, when I modify template page file, it is done by only add global $wpdb for databse operation without including wp-config file.

Now, I create my own php file in public_html folder for database operation. For this to work, I should include wp-config.php file.

My question is should I add global $wpdb if I have already include wp-config.php file?

Thx

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, you are most likely doing it wrong

Comment: Hello @MarkKaplun could you please assist me about how to do it in the right way?

Comment: you should have moe details in your question, as it is it the only thing that is possible to understand from it is that you are trying to do something in non reccomended way

Answer (score 0):

If you need a processing endpoint with access to the WordPress API, use the [`admin_post_`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)) action and eliminate the need to manually include `wp-config.php` or any other WordPress files.

```
// add for logged-in visitors
add_action( 'admin_post_your_action', 'prefix_your_action_function' );
// for non logged-in visitors
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_your_action', 'prefix_your_action_function' );
function prefix_your_action_function() {
    global $wpdb;
    // your processing code here
}
```

Use [`admin_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) to target the file in WordPress context, like:

```
echo admin_url( 'admin-post.php?action=your_action' );
```

You can `GET` or `POST` whatever additional data you need to pass.

Comment: Hello @Milo first of all, thanks for your fast answer. I'm sorry if you are confused about my question. I think this is the answer that I need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798986/i-have-include-wp-config-should-i-add-global-wpdb-also

Comment: I'm not confused about your question, you're doing something that is not recommended, I'm showing you an alternative.